# Python attribute of combination of two objects

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I am fairly new to OOP in Python. In a program, I have two types of class:

```
class Character:
    ... etc. ...
```

[`Character1` and `Character2` are instances of this]

and

```
class Room:
    ... etc. ...
```

[`Room1` and `Room2` are instances of this]

I want to have a variable `pos` for each `Character` and `Room` such that there is one attribute `pos` for each possible combination of the two classes:

For example:

```
Character1 with Room1 --> pos = (10, 4)
Character2 with Room1 --> pos = (6, 10)
Character1 with Room2 --> pos = (3, 12)
Character2 with Room2 --> pos = (7, 5)
```

Is there a simple way to create an attribute for a combination of classes as I have described? I have looked around the internet and have not found a way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to create a tuple of your character and room instances, then use that tuple as a key for a dict to store the value of the pos.

```
d = {}  
d[(Character1, Room1)] = (10, 4)
```

You may also wish to create a collection of characters and rooms, to allow for iteration of each.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be with a dictionary used for lookup:

```
positions = {
  (character1, room1): (10, 4),
  (character2, room1): (6, 10),
  ...
}
```

You can then just lookup the position like so:

```
pos = positions[characterX, roomY]
```

Also as a side note that might interest you, unless you're using Python 3 only, always derive your classes from object:

```
class Character(object):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're thinking about this wrong. Here's what I've done in the past.

```
class Coordinate(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Coordinate({x},{y})".format(x=self.x, y=self.y)

class Room(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.contains = list()
    def addPerson(self,person,where):
        self.contains.append((person,where))
        #  maybe use a dict here? I'm not sure your use case

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
```

Then use this to make people.

```
Adam = Character("Adam")
Steve = Character("Steve")
LivingRoom = Room("Living Room")
Kitchen = Room("Kitchen")

LivingRoom.addPerson(Adam, Coordinate(10,4))
LivingRoom.addPerson(Steve, Coordinate(6,10))
Kitchen.addPerson(Adam, Coordinate(3,12))
Kitchen.addPerson(Steve, Coordinate(7,5))
```

Then each room has `contains` which is iterable for each person and their location inside that room.

```
for person,location in LivingRoom.contains: # occupants might have been a better name
    print ("{0.name} is at ({1.x}, {1.y})".format(person,location))
# Adam is at (10, 4)
# Steve is at (6, 10)
```